# What licenses apply to JRE bundles created with install4j 7?

Tags: install4j

Assume I install a JRE, and run the createbundle tool of install4j **version 7** on it.

Does the bundle contain artifacts made by EJ Technology?
If yes, what license do these come with?
(The bundle would also be under the license of the original JRE, obviously.)

*Background:*
This question is about what additional licenses I might have to observe if I redistribute a bundle as part of my application.
Also, some configuration and integration tasks will be easier because I can skip the red tape for license checking, but I need an official statement from the Copyright owner to open that easy route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no additional artifacts in a JRE bundle created by install4j. Only the license of the bundled JRE applies.